# Holographic and BCS Superconductors

Tags: superconductivity, ads-cft, holographic-principle

The AdS/CFT correspondence can explain superconductors in a holographic way, using bulk gravity with a black hole in the background and a scalar field which, under suitable conditions, acquires a VEV in the IR (close to the BH horizon). Does this description of superconductivity quantitatively differs from the "usual" BCS superconductivity? If so, which observables behave differently?

Saying it differently: given a material in a superconducting phase, an experimental apparatus can discriminate whether it is a BCS superconductor or a holographic superconductor?

Comment: Do you have a  reference for this holographic description of superconductors?